# installing java VM 1.9

Tags: 64-bit, java

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have installed an application called Neuroph and it requires Java VM 1.9. I have used `java -version` to check the version and the output was this

`java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)`

I used the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install install oracle-java7-installer
```

but it didn't install the version that I need. what should I do?

**Edit:**

I removed my previous edit because it has changed the question to a new one, and I found an answer for the new question

Comment: There is no official 1.9 release yet. OpenJDK provides prerelease sources, which you could build on your system. And I went to Neuroph's website: They require Java 8, so you should install `oracle-java8-installer`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest update for Java is **1.8.0_25**. There is no Java 1.9 yet.

The command  `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` is to download Java 1.7
To download Java 1.8 use the following set of commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: There's a java 9 prerelease, but there aren't any binaries yet. It is, however, possible to build OpenJDK 9 manually: https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki/How-to-build-and-package-OpenJDK-9-on-Linux

Comment: @the_Seppi : yes you're 100% correct, but for 95% of users "there are no binaries" means "there is nothing".

Comment: I did what you said and I got this errorsha256sum mismatch jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 how can I solve it

Comment: Then the download of Java failed during the installation. Try again : `sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java8-installer`. (Maybe `sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java8-installer` works too)

Comment: I got this error for reinstall : E: Internal Error, No file name for oracle-java8-installer:amd64

Comment: Official documentation of `Neuroph` says the application needs `Java 1.8`. Of course one can use 'OpenJDK9` but I don't see why one should.